# Automate excel import data from SQL (multiple databases)

Tags: sql, excel, extract

I want to get a data dump of SQL server data into excel spreadsheets.

With Excel, importing data from an external data source (from SQL Server Database), I would be able to get data from SQL Server into the spreadsheet.

Would there be a way to automate this process
I need to put into excel files, data from 6 queries (the same 6 queries) , from a 100+ sql database instances.

Only the DB name would keep changing. Looking for advice to help automate the process.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'd leave this as a comment if I could - this is definitely doable, you could connect to the sqlserver instance with VBA, execute your queries to return Recordset objects, use CopyFromRecordset to paste the result to Excel, and then save the workbook.

If you need to do it for 100+ databases, you can just run the script on a loop, and update the database name in your connection string each time

This has a complete example for connecting to a DB, return a query as a recordset, and pasting it into Excel:
https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/vba-to-connect-to-sql-server.617788/

If you haven't done this before , getting the connection string right the first time is usually tricky - and if you don't have experience with VBA you may need help learning to add worksheets/save workbooks, but that's a separate issue